# what is the difference between s3 download and getobject

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

My question is with reference to aws sdk for golang. There are two ways to download a file

- GetObject
- Download (S3Manager)

I understand that Download uses concurrent GET requests to download a file. If this is the case, is not this always a better option? If not, could you please advise when to use GetObject method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetObject` is a low-level [call to S3 rest API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html). Downloader it's using it internally for concurrent download of chunks of the requested file. So, for example, it makes sense to use it in case you want to write your custom downloader. As an end user, you should stick with Downloader.